# Importing an es6 module that may not exist

Tags: ember-cli

Just say I create an addon that is shared with other users and I need to import ember-data.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
```

How can I import this given it might not exist in the client code.  Basically I need a condition to check if ember-data is available, if so import it and do something, else don't do it.

```
if(ember data exists) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Your dependencies should be in your `package.json` file.

Comment: But I don't want to force the client to ship ember data if they don't want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same question for general es6 usage, but assuming you're using ember-cli you can look at the `require._eak_seen` object so your code could potentially look something like:

```
if(require._eak_seen['ember-data']){
  //your code
}
```